# How to limit the fan speed to X until temperature Y? (or similar)

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

Even though my laptop is cold, whenever I plugged it in, fan speed increases. How can I manually override the settings so that the fan speed is limited to X until temperature Y (or something similar)?

When I limit the CPU frequency to 0.77 GHz it stops the noise, but it is extremely slow.

Again, the laptop is not that hot. It's modern and clean, and it is very silent when it's not charging.

Laptop: Samsung series 9 15inch (NP900X4C)

SpeedFan doesn't detect my fans.

Comment: If you `SpeedFan` doesn't detect any fans then you won't have the capability to do what you want.

Comment: How can you be sure?

Comment: Years of experience

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, SpeedFan is the most propable way to go.
Sometimes on a Linux lm_sensors detects more though.

All the rest: Difficult to impossible.

I have made a GUI wrapper [here](https://github.com/LeonardKoenig/FanSetQt) for [this](https://github.com/LeonardKoenig/Acer_FanMaximiser) which is just a small cleaned-up fork as inidicated by GitHub.
It's confirmed working on some Acer models but I could imagine that more than these have the same EC. Especially, if you have Insyde H2O Bios.

You can try - but it's risky. It's your decision whether you try it or not.